# Is there a way using Imagick in PHP to flush the first frame of a GIF/WebP image?

Tags: php, imagemagick, image-resizing, imagick, webp

I'm using ImageMagick to dynamically resize avatars and serve them. This has proven to be a great benefit to development as when we build out new pages, we don't know how large an image should be.

Here's an example of how I am doing this:

First my file runs through and checks headers for if it needs to be re-generated:

```php
$ModifiedDate = filemtime($UseFile);

header('Last-Modified: '.date(DATE_RFC2822, $ModifiedDate));
header("Cache-Control: public, max-age=66600");
header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time() + 66600));

if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE"]))
{
    $ModifiedSince = strtotime($_SERVER["HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE"]);
    if($ModifiedDate <= $ModifiedSince)
    {
        header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 304 Not Modified");
        die;
    }
}
```

Then we determine the highest size available:

```php
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($UseFile);
$NewSize = $_GET["Size"]; // I handle sanitizing this, I removed sanitation code to make this code simpler as it is not the problem I am encountering
if($NewSize > $width || $NewSize <= 0)
    $NewSize = $width;
```

Then we handle resizing of the image:

```php
header("Content-type: image/" . ($Animated ? "webp" : "jpg"));
$Avatar = new imagick($UseFile);

if ($Animated)
{
    $Avatar = $Avatar->coalesceImages();

    foreach ($Avatar as $Frame)
    {
        $Frame->cropThumbnailImage($NewSize, $NewSize);
        $Frame->setImagePage($NewSize, $NewSize, 0, 0);
    }
}
else
{
    $Avatar->cropThumbnailImage($NewSize, $NewSize);
}
```

Then we return the image to the user:

```php
echo $Avatar->getImagesBlob();
$Avatar->clear();
```

However, we recently added the ability for users to upload GIFs and we will serve them as animated  webp images. We've noticed that while this functionality works, it can be extremely slow to resize.

Is there a way to potentially speed this up, maybe by flushing the first frame once it has been generated? I'm having trouble finding any information about this online, so maybe this isn't feasible.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your issue. Removing one frame from an animation would not help much in speed. Resizing an animated GIF has to resize each frame. However, if you only want to process one frame, then simply add [0] to the end of your filename, such as animated.gif[0].  That will only process the first frame of the animation. See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#list_ops

Comment: @fmw42 I'm not sure if my question is even logical in terms of how webp files work, but I figure it is worth asking. What I'm asking is if there is that once the first frame has been resized, if it can be returned to the client while the remaining frames are processed.

Comment: The only way I can think to do that is to save each processed frame as its own image file. But I do not know much about serving it after it has been processed while continuing the other frames. ImageMagick programming can save separate files in addition to the final animation, if you want both.